# Way to hide some form fields for user xyz

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

at the moment I'm using this way to get the 'role' of an user in a `ZEND_FORM`.

```
$identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
```

For every form field I check for the role in front of adding the form field like:

```
if($identity->role=='admin') $form->addElement...
```

Is there a smarter way to do this? Such as an option for the addElement?

Best Regards
Frgtv10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do it could get messy. Its possible you could use 2 forms here. One main one containing what is common to everyone and one that inherits from the first one and adds fonctionnality for admins. This would be much easier to maintain since you would just instantiate the right form depending on role so one check for role instead of a ton everywhere in your form.

So in your controller you would :

```
if($identity->role=='admin'){
   $form = new Form_WhateverAdmin();
} else {
   $form = new Form_WhateverNotAdmin();
}
```

And where

```
Form_WhateverNotAdmin extends Zend_Form
```

and

```
Form_WhateverAdmin extends Form_WhateverNotAdmin
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can delete existing elemets:

```
if($identity->role != 'admin') $form->removeElement('name');
```